# How can I display entries from the past 2 weeks, and have it refresh every two weeks?

Tags: parameters

```
{exp:channel:entries site="nxtsports" channel="blog" dynamic="no" limit="5" status="open|Preview" {global:disable_basic} orderby="view_count_one" {!--display_by="week" start_day="Monday"--}}
                {snp_global_blog_article_listed}
                This has been seen {view_count_one} times!                  

            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Anyone know how to use the display_by parameters I commented out to display the top 5 entries with the most views from the past 2 weeks?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [sample of this code on user guide](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on). You need to use the `start-on` parameter and to enable PHP to run at input on the template:

```
<?php
        $start_time = ee()->localize->format_date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i', ee()->localize->now - (60*60*24*14));
?>

{exp:channel:entries start_on="<?php echo $start_time; ?>" site="nxtsports" channel="blog" dynamic="no" limit="5" status="open|Preview" {global:disable_basic} orderby="view_count_one"}
    {snp_global_blog_article_listed}
    This has been seen {view_count_one} times!                  
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Oh dear, RT*M :( , it's worth noting you should set PHP to run on _input_ so that the PHP date is inserted before the channel tag is parsed.